# Rails - how to join multiple post parameters to create model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model which has three datetime attributes date, time_in and time_out.

In my UI I have Virtual Attribute form fields for:

- date_v: YYYY/MM/DD
- time_in_v: HH:MM
- time_out_v: HH:MM

On *before_validation* I want to create the correct time attributes before saving. The functions I have can create the time values no problem but the issue I have is being able to access the values of the virtual attributes from the form.

I've tried in my model - before_validation and I've also tried in my controller as a before_action for create & update.

I'm new to Rails/MVC and I'm not sure where/how I should be going about this. All the examples I've found for processing data before submission work on filtering one value rather than merging two different values and I can't work out how to access the values I need.

The functions I'm using are below. Neither work. The controller throws an error. The model one returns invalid because the datetime fields are not set.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

#### Model - before_validation

```
def setup_dates
    self.date = Time.parse( date_v + ' ' + time_in_v + ':00 UTC') if date_v.present? && time_in_v.present?;
end
  # self.date = Time.parse( '2012/12/14 13:14:00 UTC'); Works Fine
  # I've also tried referencing these vals by e.g. self.time_in_v
```

#### Controller - before_action

```
def set_dates
  @dive.date = Time.parse( params[:date_v] + ' ' + params[:time_in_v] + ':00 UTC')
end
# Throws error: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

**###### EDIT / UPDATE #######**

I noticed the upvote on this q so here's the solution I ended up using:

I went with filtering the values in the controller. The reason my initial attempt at this failed is because I wasn't accessing the parameters properly.

It needed:

```
params[:model][:parameter]
```

when I was trying to access:

```
params[:parameter]
```

My solution:

```
before_action :set_datetimes, only: [:create, :update]

 def set_datetimes
      if params[:dive][:date_v].present? && params[:dive][:time_in_v].present? && params[:dive][:time_out_v].present?
        params[:dive][:date] = Time.parse( params[:dive][:date_v] + ' ' + params[:dive][:time_in_v] + ':00 UTC')
        params[:dive][:time_in] = params[:dive][:date]
        params[:dive][:time_out] = Time.parse( params[:dive][:date_v] + ' ' + params[:dive][:time_out_v] + ':00 UTC')
      end
  end
```